# Particles System not showing up on Viewport

Tags: particles

I'm having some trouble with the Particles System here.
You guys may know the Grass Essentials pack by Andrew Price.
For those who don't know it, I have the scene below with some grass meshes in a group.

[image]

I'm trying to apply this group of meshes on the selected plane by their side, but (I don't know why) It's not working. By the pack default, the plane is already set with the particles system, but it's not showing up.

I have the file here in this link (Ball.blend - 25,087 KB): http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=45847

If someone can help me, I would be very thankful.

Comment: Forgot to inform that my version of blender is 2.78a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Particle System modifier has disabled visibility.

[image]

Go into the plane object modifier stack and turn on visibility for the particle system modifier

Comment: What a shame! HAHAHA! Thank you so much @DuarteFarrajotaRamos. It was under my nose and I didn't see it.